# How do I access a JSON property that is nested within an id, without hardcoding the id?

Tags: json, typescript

I'm trying to access a property of a JSON object using TypeScript.  The JSON object is obtained from a server in this format:

```
{
  "1111": {
  "id": 1111,
  "name": "NAME",
  "available": 3,
  }
}
```

This JSON object has property names that match my typescript class, used to deserialise the JSON object into this class.
I've been able to access a property is this way:

```
jsonObj['1111'].name  //this correctly returns "NAME"
```

However, I would prefer to use the id of the JSON object as a variable, as opposed to hardcoding the id into the call to get the property.  Is there a way to do something like this?

```
let idOfJsonObj = '1111'
jsonObj[idOfJsonObj].name  //this implementation throws an error
```

Comment: What error does it throw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use:

```
let idOfJsonObj = 1111
jsonObj[idOfJsonObj].name
```

Don't use quotes.

Comment: @fuzzii No problem. Can you please accept the answer? Thanks